# ADC pin in MCU how to connect

Tags: microcontroller, adc

I want to ask how to correctly connect an ADC pin to an MCU.

I've found this two practice in some datasheets:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fd7yfI.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Which one is correct? Or how I should connect ADC pin?

Comment: Do you have any specific needs to fulfill that connecting it directly won't satisfy?

Comment: @Yaro  What will be your sensor(s) that will be providing the signal for the ADC?  What is the model of your MCU?

Comment: Which microcontroller is it for? They all have quite different input requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first schematic is terminating a 50 ohm impedance transmission line. The capacitor is likely there to provide some filtering of high frequency noise. Unless you're using a 50 ohm transmission line, this solution doesn't apply to you.

The second schematic is using a resistor to limit current through the MCU's protection diodes in the event that the signal is outside the rails. A parallel capacitor bypasses the resistor, improving the high frequency response.

What you use depends on your requirements. If you want to protect the microcontroller against signals outside the rails, a series resistor like R2 in the second schematic is useful, though it will limit its frequency response. The parallel capacitor is only likely to be important if you're measuring high frequency signals.

Comment: So, in both schematics capacitors aren't used to stabilize voltage to provide more stable and accurate reading?

Comment: @Yaro That's what the capacitor in the first schematic does.